# What is the energy decay speed for different resonator levels?

Tags: ingress

What is the energy decay speed for different resonator levels?

I know for sure that L1 resonator decays at a rate of 10% a day or 100 XM a day. I have not explicitly tested it for resonators of higher level and now I think it becomes more and more relevant.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All portals decay 15% per day.

Source: Official Niantic documentation.

[Portal Decay](http://support.google.com/ingress/answer/2808249?hl=en&ref_topic=2799270)

> Resonators are powered by XM. Resonators start with a full charge, but the XM store is consumed at a rate of approximately **15% per day.**

*(Emphasis mine)*

Portals used to drain at 10% per day, but it was increased in an update early 2013 to be 15%

Comment: That is not nice, try to recharge a lvl 4 portal even as lvl 6 player. I hoped it was not percentage based.

Comment: Maybe stupid question, but what does "per day" mean? Does it mean that at midnight all resonators loose 10% or a day at the time of deployment of the resonator?

Comment: @otakun85 I'd open a new question for that, but from anecdotal experience I believe it is the latter - the entire portal drains 15% at the minute that the portal was captured.

Answer (score 0):

Recently decay speeds are different for different resonator levels from 10% for R1 to 15% for R8

Comment: Is there a source for this?